# Insert in Cassandra in a collection values with single quote

Tags: cassandra, cql, nosql

Is there a way to insert in a collection of Cassandra a value with single quote? This is what I have:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE test.test (
   name text PRIMARY KEY,
   values map<text, text>
)
```

Insert:

```
INSERT INTO test (name, values) VALUES ( 'jos''emy',{'foo':'josemy''s house'});
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM  test;
```

```
 name    | values
---------+----------------------------
 jos'emy | {'foo': 'josemy''s house'}
```

As you can see, Cassandra replace the double quote in the simple "name" field, but does not replace the quotes in the field inside the map. The result I want is:

```
 name    | values
---------+----------------------------
 jos'emy | {'foo': 'josemy's house'}
```

Comment: I am afk, but did you try to use 'josemy\'s house' ?

Comment: yes, but it fails. The documentation says that the single quote is escaped with another single quote.

Comment: In case anyone cares, the jira created by the OP:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10263

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way.  What you are trying to do looks like it should work.  Probably someone forgot to check for escaped characters in collection strings.  You might want to enter a ticket for this if no one comes up with an answer so that it can be looked into.

[Report bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA)

Answer (score 0):

A work-around would be to do your select as JSON.

```
cqlsh:gii> insert into test (name,values) values ('Tu''pac',{'fo''o':'josemy''s house'});
cqlsh:gii> select * from test;
 name    | values
---------+------------------------------
  Tu'pac | {'fo''o': 'josemy''s house'}

cqlsh:gii> select json * from test;

 [json]
----------------------------------------------------------
 {"name": "Tu'pac", "values": {"fo'o": "josemy's house"}}
```